# NotificationCenter listening in queue

Tags: ios, swift, queue, observers, notificationcenter

I want to know the difference between

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
    ...
}
```

vs

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    ...
}
```

From Apple:

> **queue**
> The operation queue where the block runs.
> When nil, the block runs synchronously on the posting thread.

So, as I understand if I send `.main`, the block will have more priority to run? I just want to make sure to register when the app goes to background.
Is any reason or situation that either block will not be called?

Comment: In general, I wouldn’t assume that `.main` will have better performance for observers. If you post from some background thread, processing it on the current thread synchronously is likely to be more performant, though unlikely to be observably so. I wouldn't worry about this performance issue, as it is likely immaterial: The real question is whether you care on which thread the closure runs (i.e., is it doing something that requires main thread or some synchronization, for example). If so, specify the appropriate queue when you set up your observer. If not, leaving it `nil` is likely best.

Comment: If you have to do some UI related task that you should make sure that the block will execute on Main thread either by specifiying the main queue if you are the notification posting code is not executing on main thread or by making sure that your notification posting code is in main thread.

Comment: I only want to register in UserDefaults a flag whether the app goes to background or not, I have the same code but for `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` to update that flag. The reason for this is to check an OOM in the next app launch, if it was a BOOM (background out of memory), we check for other things.

Comment: I would not think that `.main` would "give it more priority".  There is a good chance that the `.didEnterBackground` notification was already posted on the main queue.  If you explicitly specify `.main` then your notification handler will be asynchronously scheduled on the main queue whereas if you specify `.nil` your handler is invoked synchronously on whatever queue it was posted from (probably the main queue). Specifying `.main` will introduce a small delay in hand,Int the notification. This may or may not matter to you